# 2 Record Rules, same object, same group, different domain

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

Human logic vs OpenERP logic, hard times.

Very simple idea: a project user should be able to see/read all the tasks, but only be able to edit/write his assigned tasks.

Easy, Record Rules on project.task:

- 1st rule:  [('user_id','!=',user.id)], grants Read
- 2nd rule:  [('user_id','=',user.id)], grants RW

Nope, 2nd rule overwrites the 1st one.

Is it me or it is really complicated to do real simple things?
Have I missed something?

Thanks

Edit: To clarify my point here are my rules 1 & 2:

```
    <record model="ir.rule" id="project_task_user_rule">
        <field name="name">Project/task: user: read others tasks</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_task"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','not in',[user.id])]</field>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('project.group_project_user'))]"/>
        <field eval="1" name="perm_read"/>
        <field eval="0" name="perm_write"/>
        <field eval="0" name="perm_create"/>
        <field eval="0" name="perm_unlink"/>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.rule" id="project_task_user_rule">
        <field name="name">Project/task: user: RW rights on his tasks</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="project.model_project_task"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('project.group_project_user'))]"/>
        <field eval="1" name="perm_read"/>
        <field eval="1" name="perm_write"/>
        <field eval="0" name="perm_create"/>
        <field eval="0" name="perm_unlink"/>
    </record>
```

In this case, the user sees only his tasks and can modify them.
If I put the second rule over the first one, user can see all the tasks, but is not able to edit any, neither his own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they don't overwrite each other, they are cumulative:
The access rule engine looks for a positive permission for the action to be done (`read`, `create`, `write`, `unlink`) in any of the available rules.

That same method is used in the OCA module `project_baseuser` to limit helpdesk end users to have write access only on draft/new Tasks. Once Tasks move to a started stage only Project Users can edit them. See: https://github.com/OCA/project/blob/29caef1cd8029e755c2c27d54541202d52b9c744/project_baseuser/security/project_security.xml#L79

Comment: If it is so, why in my case the user sees only his tasks with right permission, and if I put the 2nd rule over the 1st one in the XML, then he is able to see all the tasks but not able to write on any, neither his own tasks?

Comment: By the way in your example, you do have two different groups, and a global rule. In my case the two rules applies on the same project.group_project_user.

Answer (score 0):

Alright while editing my post I figured out that I made a huge beginner mistake...

If you look at the id I gave to my records, they are the same, thus the second overwrites the first while being read.
With two different ids, of course that now works!

Thanks @Daniel Reis, somehow made me aware of that.

Cheers!